# Shortest way to assign a not null value

Tags: c#

I have a long list of code similiar to the following.  Is there a way to shorten this?

```
 pallete.ActionDefault = themeInfo.ActionDefault is not null ? themeInfo.ActionDefault : pallete.ActionDefault;
```

This just assigns a value if it is not null.  If it is null, do not assign any value.

Comment: `x = themeInfo.ActionDefault  ?? pallete.ActionDefault;`

Comment: Or the classic `if (themeInfo.ActionDefault != null) {  pallete.ActionDefault = themeInfo.ActionDefault; }` that seems a lot clearer (i.e., there is no assignment in the `null` case)

Comment: what about this `pallete.ActionDefault = themeInfo.ActionDefault ?? pallete.ActionDefault;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
only use ?? for null check. x = y ?? z
```

Comment: "Only?" That's a pretty bold statement.

Comment: Of course not only :) the shortest way.